# "mapping values are not allowed in this context at line xx" when running DelayedJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

One day on my production server with Rails 3.2.13 app DelayedJob stoped working and there was no way to run it again. I haven't made any changes on the server before. When trying to run `rake jobs:work` I saw error:

`mapping values are not allowed in this context at line xx`

this error is always connected with parsing some yaml file.

When I was searching for problem I

- restarted my app
- checked for yaml problems
- checked for system problems

and everything seemed to be fine.

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I tried to run first job from `rails console` by `DelayedJob.find(x).invoke_job` and the problem was in one specific job and its handler description. I remover this one and then started delayed_job without problem. So if you have that kind of problem start searching from your first job in queue.